# How can I find a logically equivalent equation by only using negation and conjunction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I am trying to finish up my discrete math homework, but I am completely stumped as to how I am supposed to solve this problem. My teacher wants me to find a logically equivalent equation for p v q that does not include exclusive or, implication, or inclusive or (aka she wants me to use only negation and ands). I don't want any answers, for I need to do my homework myself. But please any examples or help would be GREATLY appreciated. I feel as though there is a simple way to do this going right over my head.

Comment: `use only negation and ands` Hint: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: OH wow it was that easy to just apply a double negation. Facepalm. Thank you very much for pointing this out to me. I appreciate it!

Comment: @dxiv That hint is the type of answer sought.  Post it as one.

Comment: @GrahamKemp The OP said `I don't want any answers` ;-) Seriously now, I am just glad that my hint clicked. If the OP chooses to write a self-answer (which btw is perfectly acceptable around here) then I'll be the first one to upvote.